# Clearing Shared Preferences throws a Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I am getting a null pointer exception every time the user selects "logout" (R.Id.logout) from the option menu.  I can't figure out what I'm not initialising.

```
@Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.settings:             
                    return false;
                case R.id.about:
                    this.startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));
                    return true;
                case R.id.logout:
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    alertbox.setTitle("Logout");
                    alertbox.setMessage("Logging out will remove your credentials from this phone. \nDo you want to logout?");
                    alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                    {                   
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                        {
                            Editor e = loginPref.edit();
                            e.clear();

                            Homepage.this.startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class));
                            Homepage.this.finish();             
                        }
                    });
                    alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {                   
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                        {
                            dialog.cancel();                    
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = alertbox.show();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

logCat

```
08-16 10:09:49.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1531): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 10:09:49.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1531): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-16 10:09:49.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at org.*****.android.Homepage$1.onClick(Homepage.java:79)
08-16 10:09:49.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:158)
08-16 10:09:49.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-16 10:09:49.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-16 10:09:49.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-16 10:09:49.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 10:09:49.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-16 10:09:49.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-16 10:09:49.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-16 10:09:49.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you display your logcat error detail then we can know where you can get the null pointer exception or please check logcat and place comment on that line

Comment: where are you clearing it....? post some more code and logcat..

Comment: You're getting NPE because you call some method on variable that is null, simple. LogCat tells you about the line in your code caused NPE, so examine that line and find your not initialized variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple. Something on line 79 in Homepage.java is null. Please check what line this is and post it or post the complete code, with package name and everything so that we actually can help because now we can only guess what's actually null.

My first guess would be loginPref at:

```
  Editor e = loginPref.edit();
```

Have you initialized loginPref?

Comment: nope that was the problem loginPref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);